# Creating reusable method with variable conditional logic

Tags: c#, selenium, methods

I have several variations of the following code within methods that are being used for Selenium testing (waits for certain events before returning) and I would like to refactor it and make it reusable so I have the logic controlling the delay & try/catch as a generic method but be able to swap in and out conditions depending on situation.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Code:

```
for (int second = 0; second <= 10; second++)
    {
            try
            {
                // bit that needs to vary
                matchedAddresses = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("addresslookup"));
                if (matchedAddresses.Count > 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }          
return matchedAddresses.Count;
```

Comment: Which part of this do you want to make resuable? Seems to me that you are just getting elements count by classname. Are you looking to reuse this for various class names?

Answer (score 1):

You want function that takes argument of something like `Func<int>` - method that returns number of elements (or enumerable `Func<IEnumerable<sometype>>`)

```
public int GetCountOfElementsWithWait(Func<int> test)
{
    .....
    var count = test();
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit too obvious, but would this work?

```
public int GetCountOfElementsByClassName(string className)
{
    for (int second = 0; second <= 10; second++)
    {
        try
        {
            // bit that needs to vary
            matchedElements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName(className));
            if (matchedElements.Count > 0)
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }          
    return matchedElements.Count;
}
```